# xcodebuild: disabling "Parallelize build" (Xcode 7)

Tags: xcode7

We're using xcodebuild command line to build our nightly jobs, specifying project, target, and configuration. 
It seems like the build is done with "Parallelize build" set to "YES" by default, although we're not using schemes for the nightly builds.

This causes build errors (in detail: lipo tool tries to create a universal binary before both architectures complete building).

How can I disable the parallelization in the command line without having to create a scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've created a shared scheme (so I could later save it in the source control) and used it to define the parallelization state. That worked for me.

Comment: Good for you but it doesn't answer the question! :)